# How do I search an id in a string attribute (SQL)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In my chat app I want to calculate the response rate for student model.

I track all conversations with a `slug` attribute. It's a string like this: `270-77`, which means that this is a conversation between student `270` and recruiter `77`.

Now I want to check how many conversations one student has. Here is my code:

```
def calculate_number_of_conversations(@student)
  @conversations = Conversation.where("slug LIKE ?", "%#{params[@student]}")
end
```

Important is that it should only search in the first part of the string because the first number in `slug` is always a student's id.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: For Student the LIKE should be `LIKE %270-%`   For Recruiter the LIKE should be `LIKE %-77%`    this should work in MySQL and PostgreSQL

Comment: Postgresql @jarlh. Thanks guys, will test it!

Comment: Your `slug` is an anti-pattern, unpack it into separate attributes as Danil Speransky suggests as soon as possible, the longer you leave it the uglier it will get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what `@student` is. I will write my examples as if it's a record.

You could use `-` to make sure it's looking for students only:

```
@conversations = Conversation.where('slug LIKE ?', "#{@student.id}-%")
```

But I think it's better to have explicit relationships:

```
class Conversation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :recruiter
end

@conversations = @student.conversations
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look. This query gives me all conversation that contain the student_id. So if I search with student_id "9", I get conversation from students with id: 9,99,297, etc. How do I seach for a specific number?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the '-' to the WHERE LIKE clause:

```
def calculate_number_of_conversations(@student)
    @conversations = Conversation.where("slug LIKE ?", "%#{params[@student]}-")
end
```

Comment: When I try to search for student_id 9 for example it gives me all the conversations with student_ids with a '9'. So also 297, 99, 91 etc. How should I only target the specific string?